# 5 IIS Application Pools for Exchange 2007

Tags: iis, exchange-2007

Is there any good reason why Exchange creates so many application pools in IIS? 
Can all those applications be configured to use 1 app Pool instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there certainly are good reasons (isolation, security, etc.); but the main one is, they designed it to work this way: changing this configuration would bring you straight into Unsupported Land, which is a place where you don't want to go unless you *really* know what you're doing.

Appliation Pools have no performance impact by themselves, there really is no good reason to want to move from 5 to, say, 3 or 1.

I strongly suggest you leave them as they are.